# How do I read a yaml file and outputting the yaml file values as environment variables?

Tags: bash, yaml, github-actions

I have my environment variables stored in a YAML file. The YAML file is used by a third party service for deployment.

I was wondering if there is a way to source the YAML file I am using, so that I can get access to my database credentials to run a migration once the app has been deployed?

example YAML:

```yaml
env_variables:
  DATABASE_CONNECTION_ADDRESS: 'localhost'
  DATABASE_PORT: '5432'
  DATABASE_NAME: 'a-db'
  DATABASE_USERNAME: 'user'
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: 'password'
  IS_DEBUG: 'false'
  GS_BUCKET_NAME: image-bucket
```

My main motivation is that this deployment is running in a pipeline and I do not want to maintain the duplication of each of these environment variables in their own secret, and storing this YAML file as a secret so the third party service has access to it.

Comment: As you probably don't want everything from your YAML file, but just the environment variables it would be good to include an example that shows where in the datastructure represented by the YAML file the env. vars are defined (and how: key-value pairs, list of lists of key-values). That way also those not familiar with github-actions, might be able to help. Bash on its own cannot handle YAML in general, what programs are available?

Comment: There is [an action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/convert-json-to-env) that does it for JSON to ENV variables. Doing something similar for YAML might not be too complicated.

Comment: hello @Anthon, I have added an example like you asked. I could use any program that you recommend.

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yeah, that is very close to what I am looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Python installed in your environment and can install `ruamel.yaml` in there you can source the output of the following one-liner:

```
python -c 'from pathlib import Path; from ruamel.yaml import YAML; print("".join([f"{k}={v}\n" for k, v in YAML().load(Path("example.yaml"))["env_variables"].items()]))'
```

Its output is:

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION_ADDRESS=localhost
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_NAME=a-db
DATABASE_USERNAME=user
DATABASE_PASSWORD=password
IS_DEBUG=false
GS_BUCKET_NAME=image-bucket
```

As Jeff Schaller suggested you probably want to quote the values and escape any single quotes that might occur in the string. This can easily be achieved by changing `{v}` into `{v!r}` in the one-liner.

As program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

file_in = Path("example.yaml")

yaml = YAML()
env_data = yaml.load(file_in)["env_variables"]
print("".join([f"{k}={v!r}\n" for k, v in env_data.items()]))
```

Comment: You could have the variables become part of the current shell with `set -a; eval $(python -c ...); set +a`. I was working on a similar solution and quoted the values (surround their `{v}` values with single quotes and use `v.replace("'", r"'\''")`)

Comment: @JeffSchaller Using eval is probably more appropriate than trying to source things. I am not sure if you'd be better of using `repr(v)` instead of quoting and using replace. I think that has the same effect you are trying to achieve (single quotes around the value and any single quotes in the value itself escaped). In the format string you can get that with `!r`

Comment: Is there anyway to make this more maintainable and readable? also what is `set -a` and `set +a` do exactly?

Comment: @JoshMartin You can change the one-liner into a program by taking everything between single quotes and replacing the semicolons by newlines, and then making the extraction a seperate statement. In  the bash man page you can find `set -a`: `Each variable or function that is created or modified is given the export attribute and marked for  export to the environment of subsequent commands`  (+a turns that off)